# save text on imageview when I share it

Tags: android, draw

I'm capturing an `Image` on my app & I'm writing text on top of the image but when I try to share it, It doesn't show like it has captured the Text on Image I only see an `Image`.

This app is like Meme generator app..any help would be appreciated.

```
btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                View content = findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
                content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                content.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = ivImage.getDrawingCache();
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
                try {
                    cachePath.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/*");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(cachePath));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"));

            }
        });

        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: post your code of sharing, what you are sharing?

Comment: uploaded my code to Share..

Comment: uploaded my code to share, I have ImageView,Edittext,TextView ..after my image captured I'm able to put text on the image but I'm not able to share image with text it only shows Image.

Comment: because you are capturing image of `ImageView` only, you need to capture image of your whole layout

Comment: any suggestions to modify code please.

Comment: instead of R.id.ivImage, give your main layout id

Comment: so is it like R.id.Relativelayout? if I add this it doesn't share my imageview at all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ImageView` you need to capture layout image.

Replace this

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
```

with

```
View content = findViewById(yourLayoutID);
```

yourLayoutId = layout which consists `ImageView` + `TextView` which you want to share.

Comment: unfortunately its not working for me. I've added my layoutid as suggested by you it says cannot find the symbol layout   findviewByID(layout)

Comment: you need to add id of your layout which consist imageview + textview.

Comment: to my Relativelayout I've given an Id:layout and I've added the same here. is it not the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

```
String text= "Write your text on image";
 Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    textPaint.setTextSize(25);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);

     Bitmap bitmap = ivImage.getDrawingCache();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawText(text, 880, 30, textPaint);
```

Comment: Please do not post code without any supporting text.  Explain why this would solve the OP's problem  Help others to understand.

Comment: What is jobNum in canvas.drawText(jobNum, 880, 30, textPaint);

Comment: it is the text you want to write on image

Comment: you can put multiple lines according to position x,y which is 2nd and 3rd parameter

Comment: is it text variable? where do we need to define it?

Comment: you directly write the text as a string

Comment: check the coad again i can update the code

Comment: Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        textPaint.setTextSize(25);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);

        Bitmap bitmap = ivImage.getDrawingCache();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(textView),880, 30, textPaint)

Comment: now error: android.graphics.Bitmap android.widget.ImageView.getDrawingCache()' on a null object reference

Comment: budy you can use your code with canvass you need to use that bitmap which you set  in imageview

Comment: This is getting more interesting, now I see some random text with parameters when I share the image...

Comment: is this code is working fine now

Comment: unfortunately not, I'm still trying to figureout when I add this line to my code, I see some random text generating on imageview when I try to share the image.  and if i add canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,830,34,textPaint); no text is displayed when saving image.. I'm almost close to finish this but not getting there

Comment: get the height and width of bitmap and set the text at haft the height and width as x and y width is for x and height is for y

Answer (score 0):

in your code you only call the image so the text doesn't show up, you can achieve to get all image from the layout that contains image and text using this code it will return Bitmap, and you can share it or pass it whatever you want,

```
private Bitmap getBitMapFromLayout(Context context ,Activity activity) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //Inflate the layout into a view and configure it the way you like
        RelativeLayout view = new RelativeLayout(activity);
        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutContainsImageAndTExt, view, true);

        //you can set Image or Text view here
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);



        //Provide it with a layout params. It should necessarily be wrapping the
        //content as we not really going to have a parent for it.
        view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //Pre-measure the view so that height and width don't remain null.
        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        //Assign a size and position to the view and all of its descendants
        view.layout(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

        //Create the bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Create a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);

        //Render this view (and all of its children) to the given Canvas
        view.draw(c);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: is R.layout.yourLayoutContainsImageAndTExt is the Id which I need to assign to RelativeLayout and if this layout contains any Imagebutton will that also be included when we share

Comment: how do I add "getBitMapFromLayout" to share my Share code.

Comment: here is my existing code to share:

Comment: Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/*");  
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(cachePath));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via")
            }
        });

Comment: you can save the bitmap to a file, and reference the path of the file hope it helps,